# Javascript json filter with arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I was wondering how I can filter the values "tags" in the json above using an arrow function:

```
const ttag = [{
    "code": 795302828,
    "code_integration": "123",
    "company": "ACME LTD",
    "phone": "135575788",
    "tags": [{"tag": "companyAA"},
             {"tag": "companyBB"},
             {"tag": "companyCC"},
             {"tag": "companyDD"}
            ],
    "status": "Y"
}]

const onlyTags = ttag.filter(f => f.tags)
console.log(onlyTags)
```

**expected result:
['companyAA', 'companyBB', 'companyCC', 'companyDD']**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that's not how `filter` method works. `Filter` returns an array with values that are `true` for function passed as the argument. More you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

You could use `map` & `flatMap`, like this:

```js
ttag.flatMap(f => f.tags.map(t => t.tag));
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns array of values specified in the passed method. [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) does the same, but if the result is an array it flattens it, so result is an array of strings instead of an array of arrays of strings.

#### Important

`flatMap` is not supported in Internet Explorer, but it's already unsupported browser so I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your array and push the results to a new array, something like this

```js
const ttag = [{
    "code": 795302828,
    "code_integration": "123",
    "company": "ACME LTD",
    "phone": "135575788",
    "tags": [{"tag": "companyAA"},
             {"tag": "companyBB"},
             {"tag": "companyCC"},
             {"tag": "companyDD"}
            ],
    "status": "Y"
}]

const res = [];
ttag.forEach(x => {
    x.tags.forEach(y => {
        res.push(y.tag);
    })
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an ugly way to do it, but with the first `.map` you get each item of the main array, and with the second `.map` an array of tags inside it.

```js
const ttag = [{
    "code": 795302828,
    "code_integration": "123",
    "company": "ACME LTD",
    "phone": "135575788",
    "tags": [{"tag": "companyAA"},
             {"tag": "companyBB"},
             {"tag": "companyCC"},
             {"tag": "companyDD"}
            ],
    "status": "Y"
}]

const onlyTags = ttag.map(f => f.tags.map(t => t.tag));
console.log(onlyTags);
console.log(onlyTags[0]); // expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using map and reduce. At the end the array is flatten so it returns only an array containing the city names

```js
const ttag = [{
  "code": 795302828,
  "code_integration": "123",
  "company": "ACME LTD",
  "phone": "135575788",
  "tags": [{
      "tag": "companyAA"
    },
    {
      "tag": "companyBB"
    },
    {
      "tag": "companyCC"
    },
    {
      "tag": "companyDD"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Y"
}]

const result = ttag.map(obj => obj.tags.reduce((acc, next) => [...acc, next.tag], [])).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Array.flat() is not supported in IE too

Answer (score 0):

This should work in all browsers I believe:

```js
const ttag = [
  {
      "code": 795302828,
      "code_integration": "123",
      "company": "ACME LTD",
      "phone": "135575788",
      "tags": [{"tag": "companyAA"},
               {"tag": "companyBB"},
               {"tag": "companyCC"},
               {"tag": "companyDD"}
              ],
      "status": "Y"
  },
  {
      "code": 795302829,
      "code_integration": "124",
      "company": "ACME2 LTD",
      "phone": "135575789",
      "tags": [{"tag": "companyEE"},
               {"tag": "companyFF"},
               {"tag": "companyJJ"}
              ],
      "status": "Y"
  }
]

const onlyTags = ttag.map(f => f.tags.map(t => t.tag)).reduce((p, c) => [].concat(p,c));
console.log(onlyTags);
```